# How to copy TableView cell data to a NSMutable Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm quite new to iphone development. I created To-Do List app using coredata. so, my table view dynamically updating.
I want to add table view row textlabels to a NSMutable array (that means row1 text label to 1st index position of MutableArray , row2 text label to 2nd index position of Array)

this is my table view cellfor indexpath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *HeroTableViewCell = @"HeroTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HeroTableViewCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:HeroTableViewCell] autorelease];
    }
    NSManagedObject *oneHero = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger tab = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:tabBar.selectedItem];
    switch (tab) {
        case kByName:
            cell.textLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"name"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"];
            break;
        case kBySecretIdentity:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"name"];
            cell.textLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"];
        default:
            break;
    }


    //listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];

    //if(indexPath.row==1){
             //[listData addObject: cell.textLabel.text];


    return cell;
}
```

commented lines are how I'm try to do it. But I'm struggle to add those data as I want.
Please help me

Comment: Seems like you've got it backward -- the data should be coming from the array and copied to the table cell. Could you edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're already retrieving the objects from Core Data. Why do you need to copy the data from these cells into another array?

Comment: you can directly fetch from coredata (tableview datasource) and pass it to an array no?? http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/     in this link check the code for timetablecontroller.m

Comment: Please stop reposting your question, edit your question instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the line `listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];` some where out of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, so that it won't be  reallocated every time a cell loads. And you can have the line `[listData addObject: [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"]];`
 where it is now currently.

**Edit:** Better you can do this at some method, like *viewDidLoad:*, to make sure all elements are added to the array.

```
listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

for (NSManagedObject *oneHero in [self.fetchedResultsController allObjects]) {

    [listData addObject: [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"]];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I put **listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];** in viewdidLoad method. But then I try to retrieve objects from listData, like this **NSString *str1 = [listData objectAtIndex:1];** then exceptions occur, please tell me why ?????

Comment: Yes. Remove the **autorelease** from the line `listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];` listdata got released at that time you access its elements, because of that autorelease.

Comment: yes, I already tried it. when I print the Array, it shows all the elements :) But problem occur only when I try like this **NSString *str1 = [listData objectAtIndex:1];** if I put objectAtIndex:0 , it woks fine :(

Comment: @Sanjeewa Gunathilake, How many elements are there in the array?

Comment: @ EmptyStack, since this is To-Do List application, number of items changing

Comment: @Sanjeewa Gunathilake, No. I mean how many elements were there when you tried to access object at index 1?

Comment: @ EmptyStack,  three elements, This is the out put console **2011-06-29 16:41:03.991 SuperDB[3369:20b] (
    Unknown,
    Unknown,
    fhdfhdh
)
**  Unknown is a default value ;)

Comment: @Sanjeewa Gunathilake, Are you sure that they are strings?

Comment: @ EmptyStack, yes, when **NSString *str1 = [listData objectAtIndex:0];** its work fine, BUT give all elements of the array, (**not** only index0 element)

Comment: @Sanjeewa Gunathilake, So, `[oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"]` contains array?

Comment: @ EmptyStack, I'm not clearly get what you say. oneHero is an entity, it's attributes are "name" and "secretIdentity", both are strings. I want to get those all secretIdentitys to the array

Comment: @Sanjeewa Gunathilake, What is the output of `[listData count]`?

Comment: @ EmptyStack, it works fine, it gives 1,2,3 . . . when I adding elements

Answer (score 2):

First: you should retrieve this data from the datasource. 
Second: if you want to implement it the way you are doing it...then make sure you allocate the array only once like this:

```
if(array == nil)
{
  array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

This will have significant problems because cellForRow is called several times and with every reload you will end up adding duplicates.

Best way would be to use your oneHero object at the specific index to find the text.

Comment: I tried like this. but the problem is when I try to retrieve NSString *str2 = [listData objectAtIndex:1]; it gives exception. listData array only have index 0

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually what I want to do is, retrieve all the names(those are location names) from my **"oneHero"** object and then show those locations in a mapView. That's why I want to copy those names in to **seperate NSMutable array or just as Strings**  
Can you please give me a cording help . . .

Comment: you mean NSManagedObject *oneHero = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:anIndex]; is giving exception outside tableView delegate? Can you give more details on what is self.fetchResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

so simple , define a 
NSMUtableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then add in the switch in each case

```
[arr addObject:@"Object You Want To Add"];
```

Comment: Are you proposing a separate `case` for every object you want to be in the array?! What happens when the number of items changes?

Comment: no I suggest that when you load data in each cell is the right place to enter the data on the array, look at the example upon you see that he have two cases so addobjectsm in each case

Comment: Then the order that objects are added to the array will be arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually what I want to do is, retrieve all the names(those are location names) from my **"oneHero"** object and then show those locations in a mapView. That's why I want to copy those names in to **seperate NSMutable array or just as Strings**  
Can you please give me a cording help . . .